# Ionic how to change CLI user

Tags: ionic-framework, command-line-interface

I started to use Ionic io for a project, and I transferred the ownership of an app from my email account to the one of the company. I did this through the apps.ionic.io admin panel, but how can I set the user from the CLI? I intend to upload now the latest version of the project to the new account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run

```
rm -fr ~/.ionic/
```

and then

```
$ ionic io init
```

to sign with the new login data.